# query braces position

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues with this. Is this the right position for the braces?

```
WHERE (Q.qus_title LIKE '%".$search_Q."%' OR Q.qus_description LIKE '%".$search_Q."%') 
      AND A.qus_id is null 
ORDER BY
```

Comment: Is it working for you?  What are you trying to search for?  Provide a more comprehensive explanation of what is or what is not happening.

Comment: Is not working. Showing blank. No errors and that makes it more confusing. I was thinking may be there is a syntax or logical errors.

Comment: Avoid building SQL through string concatenation of static and dynamic data. Use prepared statements and bound parameters (provided your DB library supports them - most do now).

Comment: Still learning PDO(prepared statements and bound parameters)approach. Just trying to use what I already know to meet set deadlines...Definitely something to consider in subsequent projects. Any pointers? Except for the hard-to-follow examples in php.net, i'm yet to see real world examples...form input etc..I guess my main challenge is how to get dynamic data into Prepared statements...

Answer (score 0):

Braces in WHERE CLAUSE expressions are evaluated in exactly the same manner as code or maths

So

(Cond1 AND Cond2) OR Cond3

Would require either *Both* 1 and 2 be true *or* 3 be true

Your WHERE clause seems to say entries with a null `A.qus_id` and a `Q.qus_title` or `Q.qus_description` that contains your search text (I'm hoping your search variable is properly escaped so can't contain apostrophe's etc - ala SQL injection).

To try and find out why it's not working, run the query with NO where clause and check you get results - then keep adding terms until you find the one that's eliminating too many results.

Comment: By the way. Here is the function I am using to for escaping strings...Is this sufficient?? ----function filter($data) {
 $data = trim(htmlentities(strip_tags($data)));
 
 if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $data = stripslashes($data);
 
 $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
 
 return $data;
}

Comment: @Frank - I haven't done PHP in 2-3 years so my knowledge may be a little dated but that seems pretty comprehensive to me.

Comment: Just use bound parameters. Escaping strings for concatenation into SQL is the wrong approach.